# Multiple vertical fields in bootstrap form group not aligned properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to align different fields in a single bootstrap `form-group`. My code is:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <label for="abc">Heading1</label>
  <input type="text" id="abc" class="form-control"/>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="xyz">Heading2</label>
    <input type="email" id="xyz" class="form-control"/>
  </div>

</div>
```

This looks something like: 
[image: With Heading]

Now, what I actually want is that I don't actually have to show Heading2, so I delete it and it starts to look something like:

[image: Without Heading]

As visible, the second input box is no longer aligned with the first input box. The second one is slightly raised.

What I want is that these two boxes be perfectly aligned even without the heading label present.

Any help?
Thanks.

P.S: [Bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/wYVQJrwLYw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-3">
<label for="abc">Heading1</label>
<input type="text" id="abc" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<label for="xyz">&nbsp;</label>
<input type="email" id="xyz" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either leave the label (just delete the text in the tag so nothing shows up) to keep the proper spacing or add something like `style="margin-top: 25px"` to your second input to account for the missing label.

Answer (score 0):

Give a `min-height` for label.

```
label{
  min-height: 25px;
  display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/kMMzFgGN2A

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <label for="abc">Heading1</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="abc" class="form-control"/><br>
  <input type="email" id="xyz" class="form-control"/>
</div>
</div>
```